# combine 2 file php loginform and checklogin in one file php

Tags: php, forms, session

i have 2 php file that i use to get user login access

index.php

```
<body>
  <section class="container">
    <div class="login">
      <h1>Login to Web App</h1>
      <form method="post" action="log.php?login=cek">
        <p><input type="text" name="nik" value="" placeholder="username / nik"></p>
        <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>

        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Login"></p>
      </form>
    </div>
```

and the log.php

```
<?php
 session_start();
 include('config.php');
 mysql_connect($server,$login,$pass) or die("Nggak bisa koneksi");
 mysql_select_db($db);
 $nik = $_POST['nik'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $login = $_GET['login'];
 if($login=="cek"){ $cek = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM karyawan WHERE nik='$nik' AND password='$password'");
     if(mysql_num_rows($cek)==1) {
        $c = mysql_fetch_array($cek);
        $_SESSION['nik'] = $c['nik'];
        $_SESSION['level'] = $c['level'];
            if($c['level']=="admin") {
                header("location:main.php");
                }
            else if($c['level']=="user") {
                header("location:main.php");
                } 
            }
    else{ die("password salah <a href=\"javascript:history.back()\">kembali</a>");
    }
 }
 else if($login=="selesai"){ unset($_SESSION['nik']); unset($_SESSION['level']); header("location:index.php");
 }
?>
```

in future i'd like to combine those 2 script file in one index.php
so... if the username and/or password is false
then it will write "username/password mismatch"
inside the form

is that possible to make it ? if so .... how ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy the php code into your index.php. like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('config.php');
mysql_connect($server,$login,$pass) or die("Nggak bisa koneksi");
mysql_select_db($db);
$fail = "";  // <--------
if(isset($_POST["password"]))
{

$nik = $_POST['nik'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$cek = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM karyawan WHERE nik='$nik' AND password='$password'");
 if(mysql_num_rows($cek)==1) {
    $c = mysql_fetch_array($cek);
    $_SESSION['nik'] = $c['nik'];
    $_SESSION['level'] = $c['level'];
        if($c['level']=="admin") {
            header("location:main.php");
            }
        else if($c['level']=="user") {
            header("location:main.php");
            } 
        }
    else{ $fail = "<p style='color:red;'>invalid logindata</p>"; //<-------
 }
 }
else if($login=="selesai"){ unset($_SESSION['nik']); unset($_SESSION['level']);         header("location:index.php");
 }

 ?>
<body>
<section class="container">
<div class="login">
  <h1>Login to Web App</h1>
  <form method="post" action="log.php">
    <p><input type="text" name="nik" value="" placeholder="username / nik"></p>
    <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>
    <?php echo $fail; ?>  <----------
    <p class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Login"></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Also note the changes i made to your original code, like putting your login-check-code into an if(isset($_POST["password"])) to only fire it when the form is submitted. And I also deleted your GET-variable($_GET["login"]), since i did not saw any purpose in it.

Comment: it's error : Notice: Undefined index: login in D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\webapp\log.php on line 8 .... $nik = $_POST['nik']; | i dont know how to fix it since i have already combine both before with same result

Comment: you have to delete the line with the get-variable like i explained in my last sentence. it does not serve any purpose anyway.

Comment: it's work :D perhaps i wrong copy paste. btw how to put "red" text as a login failure notice?

Comment: woud recommend to fill a variable on a failed login like this:
      $fail="<p style='color:red'>login data incorrect</p>";
and echo it at the position you want it to appear. Remember to leave it emty by default ($fail = "") so it only appears on a failed login

Comment: can you help me with full script ? because right now index.php come with die("password salah <a href=\"javascript:history.back()\">kembali</a>" as a result when password and/or login error

Comment: just replacing it with  die("<p style='color:red;'>password salah <a href=\"javascript:history.back()\">kembali</a></p>"); shoud do the trick

Comment: no, i mean to create red notify under the form like gmail form

Comment: added the changes to my original answer (marked with <-----)

Comment: Undefined variable: fail in D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\webapp\index.php on line 49 ||| line 49 is <?php echo $fail; ?> ... happen on first time open the url .... but after trying put invalid login .... yesss... that what i mean

Comment: yeah $fail=""; needs to be outside the if-clause (updated original post)

Answer (score 0):

You Can just copy and paste your login.php code in your index.php file before your HTML code.
//HTML Code Here

```
 <html>
    <head></head>
        <body>
          <section class="container">
            <div class="login">
              <h1>Login to Web App</h1>
              <form method="post" action="log.php?login=cek">
                <p><input type="text" name="nik" value="" placeholder="username / nik"></p>
                <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>

                <p class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Login"></p>
              </form>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

//PHP Code Goes Here

```
  <?php
        session_start();
         include('config.php');
         mysql_connect($server,$login,$pass) or die("Nggak bisa koneksi");
         mysql_select_db($db);
if(isset($_POST)){

         $nik = $_POST['nik'];
         $password = $_POST['password'];
         $login = $_GET['login'];
         if($login=="cek"){ $cek = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM karyawan WHERE nik='$nik' AND password='$password'");
             if(mysql_num_rows($cek)==1) {
                $c = mysql_fetch_array($cek);
                $_SESSION['nik'] = $c['nik'];
                $_SESSION['level'] = $c['level'];
                    if($c['level']=="admin") {
                        header("location:main.php");
                        }
                    else if($c['level']=="user") {
                        header("location:main.php");
                        } 
                    }
            else{ die("password salah <a href=\"javascript:history.back()\">kembali</a>");
            }
         }
         else if($login=="selesai"){ unset($_SESSION['nik']); unset($_SESSION['level']); header("location:index.php");
         }
}
        ?>
```

After that you can handel it with javascript to show your desired popups or info.

Answer (score 0):

I would POST the form on index.php to that same page.

```
<form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<!-- Rest of the form --> 
</form>
```

Then, on top of your index.php do:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Contents of log.php        
}
```

Comment: i will test your suggestion in another day..... since i'm still learning about this programming